# how many times should setTimeout fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web site:-

```
function loadImage(src, callback) {
  var img = $('<img>').on('load', function () {
    callback.call(img);
  });

  img.attr('src', src);
  var allcaptions = $("figure span");

  // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert(1);
    $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {

      // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it (remove the img first)
      var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();
      //caption.find("img").remove();
      var t = caption.find("img").attr('data-goto');

      // caption.append($("<a />", { "text": "test", "href": t }));
      if (!(t == null || t == "undefined")) {
        caption.append("<br/>");
        caption.append("<a href='" + t + "' style='font-size:16px;font-weight:bold'>Read More</a>");
      }

      caption.find("img").remove();
      $(this).append("<div class='caption'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
    });
  }, 500);
  alert(2)
}
```

now based on my understanding is that the settimout will fires after 500 millisecond and will call the function. but what really happens is as follow:-

when the function is called (when showing image gallery), I will receive the following alerts:-

```
2
1
2
2
1 
1
```

so can anyone advice on this please, how does setTimeout works will it fires for one time only or will execute more than one time? of course I added the alerts for testing purposes only...

Thanks

Comment: setTimeout just execute the function once after N milliseconds you defined.. Probably your application is calling your loadImage function many times...

Comment: Do not debug with alerts. Use console

Comment: If you want to keep calling your function again and again after n seconds, use `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
> ```

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) has [wide support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) these days.

```js
var $container = $('.container'),
  observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      var placeholders = Array.prototype.filter.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
        return node.className === 'placeholder';
      });

      if (placeholders.length > 0) console.log(placeholders);
    });
  });

observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

var placeholders = setInterval(function() {
    $container.append('<p class="placeholder">Hello world</p>');
  }, 500),
  goodbyes = setInterval(function() {
    $container.append('<p class="goodbye">Goodbye world</p>')
  }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(placeholders);
  clearInterval(goodbyes);
}, 3500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

---

- `loadImage()` must be getting called more than once.
- [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) calls the provided function after the provided delay, just once.